Blender crashes when I enable freestyle while rendering
I don't know If this is a specific model issue but when I enable freestyle on my scene it crashes on frame 4. I tried to individually render the objects but it still crashes.


It's specific to your animation. I've tested frames 4, 18, 22, 32, and 43 with the latest Blender 4.3.1 version). The reason seems to be the objects that are scaled down to a very small size (0.0 to 0.000x). They are causing crashes at certain frames. For example, at frame #4 it's the ship (Cube.005) and at frame #32 it's the sword (Cube.002). First, the Free Style progress is very slow and then it crashes. If you disable the bad object for rendering at that frame with the camera icon in the outliner then the scene is rendered in a few seconds without any problems. The other frames were OK

@Blunder yeah I also figured this out yesterday. Turns out If there is little to no objects on the camera It just straight up crashes with freestyle. So I rendered them individually with a mix of normal and freestyle rendering. Thanks for the help anyway :)
